# Как положить метод в переменную java?

Tags: java

Есть jcombobox в котором есть лиснер в котором есть if в котором выбирается какой метод использовать. Нужно как то хранить этот выбор, чтобы вызвать его в другом методе другого класса. Я вижу так. Положить результат выбора в переменную и затем вызвать переменную там, где это необходимо. Вызвать метод напрямую пробовал но из-за необходимости jcombobox быть static не даёт его инициализировать в родительском классе

Comment: Смотря какой метод. Тип переменной будет отличаться в зависимости от сигнатуры метода.

Comment: Можно интерфейсом кинуть

Comment: Метод void в своем теле открывает файл и ищет в нем совпадения. Доберусь до дома скину код

Comment: попробовать через enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статический метод принимающий `File` и ничего не возвращающий можно сохранить в переменной так

```
Consumer<File> methodRef = SomeClass::someMethod;
```

нестатический так

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
Consumer<File> methodRef = obj::someMethod;
```

а вызвать потом так

```
methodRef.accept(new File("test.txt"));
```

Comment: В коде это выглядит так:

Class1 содержит комбобокс с итемами
comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
if (comboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Выбор первого варианта")
                  variableName = Class2.method(); - метод вызывается из другого класса Class2
     
Затем нужно вызвать результат выбора в третьем классе

Class3
 - - какая-то логика - - 
 Class1.variableName
 
То есть нужно, чтобы результат отработки if где-то хранился.
Пробовал вызвать if сразу из Class3, но в этом случае comboBox1 должен быть статичным, и при компиляции
выводится ошибка, "cannot bind: field is static"

Comment: Из вашего комментария я так и не смог понять, что вам мешает. Всем будет проще, если вы отредактируете вопрос и добавите в него [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось довольно просто. Все что мне нужно было сделать это выразить логику на bh а с pl получить лишь входящие данные. А я пытался выразить логику и ее результат на pl и запихнуть в переменную и затем передать ее на bh. Всем спасибо:)